# what is the best way to implement an activation word to a voice related project

Tags: python, audio, voice-recognition, voice

i am trying to create a voice authentication system an i have been reading and trying out related things.

but one of the feature that i want to have for my program is for it to be listen to the surrounding all the time and some function( the authentication part) to start executing after a certain activation word( for example "hello siri" for siri).

i couldn't find anything related this feature online.. can someone please help me understand the nest way to implement this function without weight the hardware too much. i really appreciate any reference you can give me

Comment: i think you looking for something like [google-speech-to-text-api](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/) to turn audio into text and check( it's an api so it doesn't impact your performance), ibm and other service also has speech to text api

Comment: @LinhNguyen this require me to send audio to the api all the time right

Comment: yes that one of the option, the google speech to text also support record by microphone if you want it to run 24/7 but i haven't done that yet so i don't know that is possible.

Comment: text to speech an compare part i think i can figure out. but but processing every second audio in using a loop is what i can't understand how

Comment: i see.. if i can directly link the mics feed to an api i think that could work

Comment: you don't have to loop or anything, you can search up `celery for python` it help your program to run a scheduled tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have raspberry pi then you can use Snowboy.

Read more [here](https://snowboy.kitt.ai/)

Comment: i am developing on windows os